# Can you explain how this NDT ultrasonic transmitter circuit works?

Tags: analysis

I am simulating the circuit shown below. I do not understand how this  works and how this will help in generating high voltage pulses for NDT ultrasonic testing.

[image: NDT ultrasonic trasmitter circuit]

Comment: Murugesh - Hi, Your original question already has an answer. Therefore you are not allowed to make a major change to it now, as answers to the new question will be different to answers to the old question. As I explained in my comment when you asked the new question as an "answer" - please [ask a new question](/questions/ask) and include the details which I explained before. For the reasons above, your edit to *this* question has been reversed ("rolled back"). Do not try to ask your new question *here* again. Instead, *ask a new question* & include a link to this one, if relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit produces high negative voltage pulses at the output.

C1 will initially be charged to the voltage of V1 via R1, R2, R6 and R7. When M1 turns on, a falling edge of 300V can be seen at the drain, which is directly forwarded via C1, D2 and R3 to the output.

R3 limits the output current to an acceptable level for the ultrasonic transducer. R4 and R5 damp the resonance ringing of the transducer.

There may also be an inductive part in the transducer. Diode D1 can protect M1 when voltage spikes above Vin come up.

Comment: I understood now, thank you